# create conditions in an unselected checkbox

Tags: php

I want to create conditions on the checkbox.
NO if the checkbox is not selected then it will be to another page but not working. please advise

```
if ($kopi == 'No')
  {
    header("Location: thank-you.php"); /* Redirect browser */
  } else {
    header("location: next.php");
    }
```

Comment: If a checkbox is not selected, it will not be included in the request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your markup 
   `<input type="checkbox" name="kopi" value="value1">`

After submitting the form you can check it with:

```
if(isset($_POST['kopi']))
{header("Location: thank-you.php"); }
else
{header("Location: location: next.php"); }
```

Comment: not acting mean but....accepting the answer as correct will help me post question in the community...!!